# Is it really necessary to explain trivial answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes

> OP: How do I rewrite `x = a + 1 + b - 1`?
>
> Me: `x = a + b`.
>
> Community: hey, you didn't explain how you did that! **Take 5 downvotes!**
>
> Me: `x = a + b` -- oh, so... you know... here I... emm... blablabla... removed `+ 1 - 1`... because it was `+ 1` and then `- 1`... you know... you I just removed it, so... ok?
>
> Community: wow, it's much better! It was totally impossible to understand until you added these two sentences to your insanely complex 4 chars edit. Thank you! **Take 2 upvotes back.**

This is pretty much what I do experience on this site for last year. I don't actually know how at all I still find a will to post any answers here with such things. If it was a way to send a private message to OP I would just send him reviewed code without letting it be attacked by such insane community attitude.

Comment: Can you share a place where this actually happened?

Comment: Also, we don't really care *how* you do things.  It is more the *why*.

Comment: @Hosch250 most of such place can not be found any more because of a bug I've reported few months ago -- moderator were just removing my answers and I had no notification about them.

Comment: Is [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/142270/9357) the post that prompted you to ask this question? Is there another example?

Comment: @Hosch250, why? "because this way the code is clearer" -- this answers almost any edit on this site, so it's pointless to say. Just a tautology to the code edit.

Comment: "Because this way the code is clearer" isn't a very good reason--that's basically "because I said so".  We like answers to state how specifically it makes the code clearer, especially with an eye toward maintenance and adding more features in the future.

Comment: You don't *have* to answer questions that warrant trivial answers, or you can find a way to provide a slightly more in-depth answer.  If you've noticed, your edit to that answer prompted the removal of the post notice.  So yes, even a simple line like that can avoid this problem.

Comment: @200_success, yes, this. And note the bug that existed (I can't  actually check if it is fixed at all) http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6888/665 -- I was not told how to run a search query for deleted answer or anything. I assume them to be from 3 to 20. I just answer and check out the notifications if I get a comment -- I didn't know I had to keep the browser tab opened to keep eye on answer deletion.

Comment: @Hosch250, how is removing `+ 1 - 1` making the code clearer? Should one comment it? It's insane.

Comment: @Jamal, that "simple line" is "avoiding the problem of getting downvoted or deleted" -- I don't want to do such pointless actions. Instead I want to help OP to clear his code. I'm sure he understood how `+ 1 - 1` is pointless -- adding text to it only wasted his time. I'm here for OPs who need my help, not for those, who are willing to delete my answers just because they don't like them.

Comment: You could also make it a comment, especially if there's already an answer to the question.  The bottom line is, if a community member doesn't like an answer, it may be downvoted.  That's how it works on this network.  Focus on actions that will get by this rather than complaining about it.

Comment: What is clear to one person may not be clear to another.

Comment: @Jamal, previous time when I made it a comment it was not enough -- people just see, that answer has no text and with no thinking about does it really need to have text besides of the code block, throw their downvote.

Comment: @Hosch250, what if I can't understand none of your answers? Should I downvote them? Or maybe downvote the whole site if I'm a noob?

Comment: If you can't understand my answers, then I'm probably not explaining the reasoning in enough detail.  You can downvote them, or, preferably, comment on them so I can fix them.

Comment: Please see this question: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5237/justify-your-review

Comment: If you have anything else you want to discuss, by all means join us in [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor). Comment streams are not the place for long-winded discussions.

Comment: What is the question on this post? From reading I'm not sure what kind of answer your are expecting...

Answer (score 15):

Your example of `x = a + 1 + b - 1` is a bit disingenuous.  As on the main site, we should be discussing real code rather than hypothetical examples.

I see from your history that this is [not your first complaint](/q/6888/9357).  The [community consensus](/q/1463/9357) is that code-only answers are not acceptable.  Several of your past answers have been forcibly deleted:

- [Alternately taking elements from an array](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/128602)
  Code dump with one line:

  > Another "little of code" approach:
  >
  > ```
  > def alternate_take a, b
  >   raise ArgumentError, "Unequal length" if a.length != b.length
  >   pool = a.zip b
  >   pool.each_slice(2){ |x, | x.rotate! }
  >   pool.map &:last
  > end
  > ```
- [Print multiplication tables](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/112216)
  Code dump with no explanation at all:

  > ```
  > def print_multiplication_table max
  >   pad = (max * max).to_s.size + 2
  >   (1..max).map do |i|
  >     (1..max).map{ |j| i*j }
  >   end.each do |row|
  >     puts ["%%%ss" % pad] * max * "" % row
  >   end
  > end
  > ```
- [Brainfuck Printer Generator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/104029)
  Mild derivative of another answer without explaining why it's better.  This one even prompted a comment from the original poster asking why you thought the solution was clearer than the original code.

  > I'll edit the @Flambino 's answer:
  >
  > ```
  > def brainturing_printer_generator(text)
  >   [0, *text.chars.map(&:ord)].each_cons(2).map do |previous, current|
  >     delta = current - previous
  >     (delta < 0 ? "-" : "+") * delta.abs + ".\n"
  >   end.join
  > end
  > ```
  >
  > And show the approach without `? "+" : "-"`:
  >
  > ```
  > SAMPLE = "-" * 255 + "+" * 255
  >
  > def brainturing_printer_generator(text)
  >   [0, *text.chars.map(&:ord)].each_cons(2).map do |previous, current|
  >     delta = current - previous
  >     SAMPLE[Range.new(*[255, 255 + delta].sort, true)] + ".\n"
  >   end.join
  > end
  > ```

Simply put, you have a history of posting answers that aren't code reviews.

---

That said, you do have a point that in some circumstances, ["Behold!"](https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10013.2.shtml) is all the explanation that is needed.  I call this the "Oh, duh!" test, and it's very difficult standard to meet.  Basically, for a code-only answer to stand, it has to be **obviously *the* "right" solution, such that once you've seen it, you could not possibly consider doing it any other way.**

So far, I have only been aware of two examples of answers that qualify:

- [Infinite list of strings containing 'a'](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/102272)
  Flagged as "Not an answer", and I declined to delete.

  > Another way to do it:
  >
  > ```
  > aStar = iterate ('a':) ""
  > ```
- [Check if a string has 20 numbers in a row in it](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/120376)

  This answer contained an alternate solution that made no reference to the original code, but I felt that none was needed.  (There were some complaints that it was not a valid answer by our rules, so I edited it for good measure.)

  > ```
  > var twentyDigits = /\d{20}/;
  > if (twentyDigits.test(myString)){
  >   console.log("My string has 20 running numbers");
  > }
  > ```
  >
  > This is using a [regular
  >   expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
  >   to look for 20 digit characters (`\d`) in a row.
  >
  > You can shorten this further as just:
  >
  > ```
  > if (/\d{20}/.test(myString)) console.log("Yup. 20");
  > ```

I don't believe that your solutions, such as this [most recent one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/142270), meet the "oh, duh!" test.

Answer (score 10):

Stack Overflow is about *solving a problem*. A question, an answer. "Try this {code dump}" are somewhat frequent and often acceptable SO answers, especially when trivial.

Code Review is about *reviewing OP's code*. It's not quite Q&A, so it's not quite "a question, an answer". "Try this {code dump}" are somewhat frequent, but never quite acceptable CR answers, *even* when trivial (excluding the odd ["oh, duh!"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7018/23788) answers).

> *This is pretty much what I do experience on this site for last year.*

The message this community is trying to get across, is that code dumps are not reviews; code dumps are not the kind of answers we value and want on this site.

A quick browse through these search results should help clarify the kind of answers we *do* value and *do* want to see on Code Review: [**Answers created after 2014-01-01, sorted by vote**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer%20created%3a2014-01-01..) (filters out older answers from before the site's scope and policies were carefully fine-tuned).

The takeaway is that we're looking for answers that provide insightful observations about the OP's code. Many excellent CR answers don't even include a code block!

If you're answering CR posts in "SO mode", you're doing it wrong.

Comment: "doing it wrong" might be a bit harsh, I'd call it "you're not doing it in the way we'd prefer".

Comment: @SimonForsberg I meant that as *You're Doing It Wrong™*.... but I see what you're saying.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that there's anything wrong with code-only answers when the point you want to make is straightforward and the code is short.

But it's also clearly the case that the community here doesn't like code-only answers, and so my advice to you is to roll with it and not fight it. There's nearly always something you can say about the reason why your suggested code is an improvement, or you could describe the language feature or API that you are using, and link to the documentation.

For example, [here's a very short answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/138888/11728) of mine that (so far) has received only upvotes:

> The documentation for [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) notes that you can pass `min` as the second argument to get a running minimum. So the maximum profit can be computed like this:
>
> ```
> profit = max(p - m for p, m in zip(prices, accumulate(prices, min)))
> ```

I feel that the one-liner passes [200_success's "Behold!" test](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7020/11728) and could stand on its own, but adding an explanation satisfies the community's requirements and might do some good.

Answer (score 1):

As luck would have it, an interesting example of a answer with minimal explanation has just been posted.

## [Comparing 2 ints without using comparative operators](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/94677/9357)

> I was looking for questions that might be asked in a technical interview and I found this one:
>
> > Write a function that determines if two integers are equal without using any comparative operators.
>
> ```
> public static boolean equal(int a, int b){
>     Integer first = a;
>     Integer sec = b;
>
>     return (first.toString()).equals(sec.toString());
> }
> ```

*Observation: this isn't such a good question for Code Review, since the artificial restriction makes it more of a Programming Puzzle.  One could argue that it violates the "Do you want this to be good code?" rule, and may therefore be off-topic.  But that would be a separate Meta question.*

### [Answer:](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/142279/9357)

> This function doesn't use any of comparative operators:
>
> ```
> public static boolean equal(int x, int y) {
>   try {
>       int r = 1/(x - y);
>   } catch (RuntimeException e) {
>       return true;
>   }
>
>   return false;
> ```
>
> }

---

The current score is +1/-4, and an "insufficient justification" moderator notice has been attached to it.

If we go strictly by the rules, this solution would need to be accompanied by an explanation such as:

> As others have said, your solution uses `String.equals()`, which arguably is a comparison operator (or uses one behind the scenes).  Here is a function that doesn't use any comparison operators.  Instead of testing `x == y`, we can detect whether `x - y == 0` by seeing whether it triggers a division by zero error.

Would that explanation add any value?  I think that "Behold!" would work just as well.  Therefore, I think that in this case, the downvotes and the moderator notice are unjustified.

Comment: As the question is not typical of this site, it doesn't make a good example. On top of that, the motivation of downvotes in this particular case is likely more than just the lack of explanation, but also the use of exceptions for flow control. (Which doesn't make the downvotes right, but it muddies the discussion we're having here.)

Comment: As the moderator who decided to put the post notice on it, I also took the decision to remove that same notice. It is indeed a "Behold!" type of answer.